# Kirby and Siebenmann obstruction for $D \neq 5$?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, geometric-topology

In 1984 old Book "Instantons_And_Four-Manifolds_Instantons and 4-Manifolds" in p.1 by Dan Freed and Karen Uhlenbeck: it says

"In 1968 Kirby and Siebenmann determined that for a topological manifold M of dimension at least five ($D=5$). there is a single obstruction $$a(M) \in H^4(M;Z_2)$$ to the existence of a PL structure."

My question is that are there examples outside dimension D=5 have this obstruction $ a(M) \in H^4(M;Z_2)$? For example

- at $D=4$, say $E_8$ manifolds?
- at any $D\geq 4$, say $E_8 \times T^{D-4}$ manifolds?

If yes, of if there are known examples, why Dan Freed and Karen Uhlenbeck only stated $D=5?$

Comment: This part of the quote looks garbled:  "... of dimension at least five $D=5$ ..." so I would suggest checking the quote again. If it actually says, or was intended to actually say, either "of dimension at least five" or "of dimension $D \ge 5$" then that would make sense and would resolve most of your question, I think.

Comment: this is the precise copy text, the puzzle is what dimensions have obstructions? $D>=4?$

Comment: As Freed and Uhlenbeck say in the quoted text, in dimension at least five (meaning, for any $n$-manifold with $n \geq 5$), there is a single obstruction to the existence of a PL structure called the Kirby-Seibenmann obstruction. This obstruction also exists for four-dimensional manifolds, but its vanishing is only a necessary condition for the existence of a PL structure, it is not sufficient.

Comment: thanks - How do we perfect it to a sufficient condition////?

Comment: You can't. A topological four-manifold admits a PL structure if and only if it admits a smooth structure, and it isn't completely understood when this occurs.